# Showing that $ \frac{a}{a^2+3}+\frac{b}{b^2+3}\leq\frac{1}{2}$ for $a,b > 0$ and $ab = 1$ using rearrangement inequalities

Tags: inequality

Please help to solve the following inequality using **rearrangement inequalities**.

> Let $a \gt 0$, $b \gt0$ and $ab=1$. Prove that 
>   \begin{equation}\frac{a}{a^2+3}+\frac{b}{b^2+3}\leq\frac{1}{2}.\end{equation}

Thanks.

Comment: You have asked so far some 26 questions (in 2 months), from which about 14 (!!) are about inequalities. I think it is about time you show a littel effort, some ideas, background...

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm sure that the ideas will appear. I want to improve my knowledges about inequalities - I hope you haven't a problem with my wish.

Comment: What DonAntonio means (I believe) is that you should probably at least mention some things you've tried in your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can assume $a \leq 1 \leq b$. Applying **rearrangement inequalities** to
$$
\begin{align}
a &\leq 1 \\
1 &\leq b
\end{align}
$$
we get 
$$
a + b \geq 1 + ab = 2
$$
and
$$
b + 3a \geq 2a + 2 \\
a + 3b \geq 2b + 2
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{a^2+3}+\frac{b}{b^2+3} &= \frac{1}{a + 3b} + \frac{1}{b + 3a} \leq\\ &\frac{1}{2b + 2} + \frac{1}{2a + 2} = \frac{a}{2a + 2} + \frac{1}{2a + 2} = \frac 1 2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a rearrangement inequality proof yet, but I really like the following proof I got.

First note that $a+b \ge 2 \sqrt{ab} = 2$ by AM-GM.

$a^2 + 3 = a^2 + 3ab = a(a+3b)  \ge a(2 + 2b) = 2ab(a + 1) = 2(a+1)$, and $b^2 + 3 = b^2 + 3ab = b(b+3a) \ge b(2 + 2a) = 2b(1+a)$.

Thus, we have
$$\frac{a}{a^2+3}+\frac{b}{b^2+3}  \le \frac{a}{2(a+1)} + \frac{1}{2(a+1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$
and we're through!

Comment: Very slick! ${}$

Comment: you can  change $a*b=1$ as $a=1/b$ put into  equation,you get cubic from which logically you can reduce it to  quadratic and solve it

Comment: @dato of course! But that proof wouldn't be too nice now, would it?

Comment: @dato: Actually, you get a quartic--even less nice! (I originally took that approach and typed it up as answer, but then remembered that the OP wanted to use rearrangement inequalities, and so I deleted it.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $ab=1$, we have $b = \frac{1}{a}$, and thus your inequality is equivalent to $\displaystyle\frac{a}{a^2+3}+\frac{a}{1+3a^2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

You can simply define $f(a) = \displaystyle\frac{a}{a^2+3}+\frac{a}{1+3a^2}$ and maximize $f$.

Comment: Where's Rearrangement Inequality involved?

Comment: Yes, I know . But I want an answer using rearrangements inequalities. Thanks, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Homogenize the given problem into,
$$\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{a+3b}+\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{b+3a}\leq \frac 12.$$
Now note that, using the AM-GM inequality we have $a+3b\geq 2\sqrt{2b(a+b)},$ so that $$\dfrac{\sqrt{ab}}{a+3b}\leq \frac{\sqrt{a}}{2\sqrt{2(a+b)}}.$$
Hence it suffices to check that $\dfrac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{2(a+b)}}\leq 1,$ which is perfectly true from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
$\Box$

Answer (score 0):

An opportunity to show the defects of **AM-GM**, you get a weaker inequailty.

$\dfrac{a^2+3}{a}=a+\dfrac{3}{a} \ge 2 \sqrt{3} \implies (\dfrac{a^2+3}{a})^{-1} \le \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}$

$\dfrac{b^2+3}{b}=b+\dfrac{3}{b} \ge 2 \sqrt{3} \implies (\dfrac{b^2+3}{b})^{-1} \le \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}$

When you add them, you have weaker inequality. Therefore, re-arrangement inequality is an appropriate one!